# showDataEffect doesn't work on dynamic LineSeries - Flex 4 mobile adobe air

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, air, mxml, linechart

In my mobile app im trying to dynamically create series in mx:LineChart. Its working.
What i need to do is applying effect when data is change.
On static series it's always work but with this it is not.
When i'm changin dataProvider for series all chart is refreshing - all series just hide and show in new positions withought Slide effect

This is my declarations

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <mx:SeriesSlide id="slideIn" duration="500" direction="down"/>
    <mx:SeriesSlide id="slideOut" duration="500" direction="up"/>
</fx:Declarations>
```

This is series creation loop

```
var s:LineSeries = new LineSeries();
s.setStyle("showDataEffect",slideIn);
s.xField = "x";
s.yField = "y";
s.setStyle("form","segment");
allSeriesLC.series.push(s);
```

after first series creation all changes i've made directly on those series - withought creating them once again. Chart id="allSeriesLC"

```
(allSeriesLC.series[i]).dataProvider = someArrayCollection;
```

Is it possible to make it work?

Comment: Did you check if your slideIn thingy is already created when you assign it to effect?

Comment: it's on my Declaration section - look up